# Como puedo obtener el codigo de una pagina web con Java y usando las cookies

Tags: java, html, cookies

mi problemas es el siguiente, quiero obtener el codigo de una pagina web, el problema es que no me la descarga, me descarga el index, al parecer las cookies se requieren para poder hacerlo.

Me podrian ayudar o explicar de como puedo hacer esto, por favor.

Comment: DaNn Jimenez, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Deberías reformular tu pregunta, es inintelegible, como poder ayudarte sin entender que necesitas.